# Simple output Chinese calendar JAVA | Find an animal + color/type from input

Tags: java, math, calendar, switch-statement, puzzle

We have an input year (1987, 2015 etc) and Chinese calendar. 
**12 animals are changing every year. 5 colors are changing every 2 year.** So the cycle is 60 years between Green Monkey and Green Monkey.
First year of that cycle is 1984 (so it's Green Monkey year).
I've got right count starting 1984, but can't come up with the right question on how to calculate it right BEFORE 1984. So when I input 2005 everything is good and when I input 1983 it counts wrong;
So my first idea and code was:

```
public static String getChineseType (int year) {
    String answer = "42";

    switch (year > 1984 ? (year-1984)%10/2 : SECOND OPTION {
        case 0: answer = "Tree/Green"; break;
        case 1: answer = "Fire/Red"; break;
        case 2: answer = "Earth/Yellow"; break;
        case 3: answer = "Metal/White"; break;
        case 4: answer = "Water/Black"; break;
        default: answer = "Wrong year num"; break;
    }
    switch (year > 1984 ? (year-1984)%12 : SECOND OPTION {
        case 0: answer += " Rat"; break;
        case 1: answer += " Ox"; break;
        case 2: answer += " Tiger"; break;
        case 3: answer += " Rabbit"; break;
        case 4: answer += " Dragon"; break;
        case 5: answer += " Snake"; break;
        case 6: answer += " Horse"; break;
        case 7: answer += " Goat"; break;
        case 8: answer += " Monkey"; break;
        case 9: answer += " Rooster"; break;
        case 10: answer += " Dog"; break;
        case 11: answer += " Pig"; break;
        default: answer += " Wrong year num"; break;
    }
    return answer;
}
}
```

So what's the best way on how to code it right **without arrays**? Or should we use different switch operators for >= 1984 and <1984?

Comment: Why are both results in the ternary operator the same?

Comment: basically 2nd options

Comment: `(year-1984)%10/2` makes my head hurt. Do you mean `(year-1984)%5` ?

Comment: You could base it in 1600 (or whatever) instead of 1984 to avoid negative numbers.

Comment: with the condition `switch (year > 1984 ? (year-1984)%12:[...])` what happens when year is `1996`? `(1996-1984)%12` is `0`, which is `Rat`, shouldn't it be `Monkey` since 12 years have passed since `1984`?

Comment: What happens if `year=1984`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(year-1984)%10/2 equals  
(year-984)%10/2， 
(year-84)%10/2 ，
(year-4)%10/2，
(year+6)%10/2
```

and the year >0

Answer (score 0):

Use a [lookup table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15114335/3735079).

First of all you need to get rid of the 1984 information. This year only gives you when the monkey occurs: `1984 % 12 = 4`, so the 4th year in the 12 cycle is Monkey year.

**NB**: here the 12 year cycle is taken starting from the year `0`! Given the information that 1984 is Monkey we can come up with which was the animal at year `0`. Our cyclic counter is not related with the *Monkey is first* thing.

Now you can create your lookup table:

```
private final static Map<Integer, String> ANIMAL_YEARS = new HashMap<Integer, String>(){{
    //Check the actual values!!
    put(0, "Rat");
    put(1, "Ox");
    put(2, "Tiger");
    ...
    put(11, "Pig");
}};
```

Now to get the animal you only need to call:

```
String animal = ANIMAL_YEARS.get(year%12);
```

The same can be done with the color:

```
private final static Map<Integer, String> COLOR_YEARS = new HashMap<Integer, String>(){{
    //Check the actual values!!
    put(0, "Tree/Green");
    put(2, "Fire/Red");
    put(4, "Earth/Yellow");
    ...
    put(8, "Water/Black");
}};
```

Then you can:

```
int decimal = year % 10;
String color = COLOR_YEARS.get(decimal%2==1?decimal-1:decimal);
```