# Update RecyclerView After Dialog

Tags: android, sqlite, dynamic, android-recyclerview

I have an app that predicts the winner of a soccer game, and I am trying to change the UI.
I made the screen where you enter the Data into a Dialog activity, and made the "History" activity the main activity. The Dialog to enter the data is called upon press of a button in the "History" activity.

Is there any way to update the recyclerView with the user's history after the dialog is terminated.

In another words, is there a way to add an entry to cardview in a recyclerview, with both new and old data in an sqlite database, when the user enters data into a Dialog Activity?

In my code, the button to start the dialog that gets the user's input is called PLUSBUTTON in my code. When the user clicks enter on the Dialog, their data is added to an SQLite database. The SQLite database is read on the creation of the Main Activity only, so obviously something will needed to be added in that aspect.

History Activity Data:

```
package com.winansbros.soccerpredictor;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.*;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;
import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;

public class History extends Activity {

Context CTX = this;

AdView mAdView;
AdRequest adRequest;

CardView GOTWCARDVIEW;

TextView GOTWHOMETEAM;
TextView GOTWAWAYTEAM;
TextView GOTWSCORE;
ImageView GOTWTEAMHOME;
ImageView GOTWTEAMAWAY;
ImageView PLUSBUTTON;

public static GoogleAnalytics analytics;
public static Tracker tracker;

DatabaseOperations DOP;

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

List<String> hometeams;
List<String> awayteams;
List<String> scores;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

    analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    analytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(1800);

    tracker = analytics.newTracker(***);
    tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
    tracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
    tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);

    tracker.setScreenName("main screen");

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    Parse.initialize(****);

    hometeams = new ArrayList<>();
    awayteams = new ArrayList<>();
    scores = new ArrayList<>();

    DOP = new DatabaseOperations(CTX);
    Cursor CR = DOP.getInformation(DOP);

    if(CR.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            hometeams.add(CR.getString(1));
            awayteams.add(CR.getString(2));
            scores.add(CR.getString(3));
            Log.d("Cloud Files", "OBJECT ID SET");
            getHistory();
        } while (CR.moveToNext());
    }

    CR.close();
    DOP.close();

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(CTX);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    GOTWCARDVIEW = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.featuredgotwcardview);
    GOTWHOMETEAM = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gotwteam1textview);
    GOTWAWAYTEAM = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gotwteam2textview);
    GOTWSCORE = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gotwpredictedscore);
    GOTWTEAMAWAY= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gotwteam2imageview);
    GOTWTEAMHOME = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gotwteam1imageview);
    PLUSBUTTON = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.newGame);

    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("8AC41E108CD62B7703FF28358AEEC8BC")
            .addTestDevice("995A71AC50F6D29195A958BA35EADD72")
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            final ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameOfTheWeek");
            query.orderByDescending("createdAt").setLimit(1);
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Log.d("name", "Retrieved GOTW successfully");
                        GOTWHOMETEAM.setText(list.get(0).getString("HomeTeam"));
                        GOTWAWAYTEAM.setText(list.get(0).getString("AwayTeam"));
                        GOTWSCORE.setText(list.get(0).getString("PredictedScore"));
                        String homeimage = list.get(0).getString("homeimage");
                        int resID= getResources().getIdentifier(homeimage, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        GOTWTEAMHOME.setImageResource(resID);
                        String awayimage = list.get(0).getString("awayimage");
                        int resID2= getResources().getIdentifier(awayimage, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        GOTWTEAMAWAY.setImageResource(resID2);
                    } else {
                        Log.d("name", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });

            GOTWCARDVIEW.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(CTX, gameoftheweekfurtherinfo.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }
    }).start();

    PLUSBUTTON.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(History.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

public void getHistory(){

    int size = hometeams.size();

    String[] myDataset = new String[hometeams.size()];
    myDataset = hometeams.toArray(myDataset);
    String[] myDataset2 = new String[awayteams.size()];
    myDataset2 = awayteams.toArray(myDataset2);
    String[] myDataset3 = new String[scores.size()];
    myDataset3 = scores.toArray(myDataset3);
    Log.d("Progress", "DOnt worry");
    Integer[] myDataset4 = new Integer[hometeams.size()];
    Integer[] myDataset5 = new Integer[awayteams.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (myDataset[i].equals("Arsenal")) {
            myDataset4[i]=(R.drawable.arsenal);
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Aston Villa")) {
            myDataset4[i]=(R.drawable.astonvilla);
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Burnley")) {
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.burnley));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Chelsea")) {
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.chelsea));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Crystal Palace")) {
            myDataset4[i]=(R.drawable.crystalpalace);
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Everton")) {
            myDataset4[i]=(R.drawable.everton);
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Hull City")) {
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.hullcity));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Leicester City")) {
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.leicestercity));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Liverpool")) {
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.liverpool));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Man City")) {
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.mancity));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Man United")) {
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.manunited));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Newcastle")) {
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.newcastle));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("QPR")) {
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.qpr));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Southampton")) {
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.southampton));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals( "Stoke City")) {
            myDataset4[i]=(R.drawable.stokecity);
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Sunderland")) {
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.sunderland));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Swansea City")) {
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.swanseacity));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Tottenham")) {
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.tottenham));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("West Brom")) {
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.westbrom));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("West Ham")){
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.westham));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Almería")) {
            myDataset4[i]=(R.drawable.almeria);
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Athletic Bilbao")) {
            myDataset4[i]=(R.drawable.athleticbilbao);
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Athlético Madrid")) {
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.athleticomadrid));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Barcalona")) {
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.barcalona));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Celta Vigo")) {
            myDataset4[i]=(R.drawable.celtavigo);
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Córdoba")) {
            myDataset4[i]=(R.drawable.cordoba);
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Deportivo La Coruña")) {
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.deportivolacoruna));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Eibar")) {
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.eibar));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Elche")) {
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.elche));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Espanyol")) {
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.espanyol));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Getafe")) {
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.getafe));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Granada")) {
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.granada));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Levante")) {
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.levante));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Málaga")) {
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.malaga));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals( "Rayo Vallecano")) {
            myDataset4[i]=(R.drawable.rayovallecano);
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Real Madrid")) {
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.realmadrid));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Real Sociedad")) {
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.realsociedad));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Sevilla")) {
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.sevilla));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Valencia")) {
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.valencia));
        } else if (myDataset[i].equals("Villarreal")){
            myDataset4[i]=((R.drawable.villarreal));
        } else {
            myDataset4[i]=(R.drawable.imageismissing);
        }

        if (myDataset2[i].equals("Arsenal")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.arsenal));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Aston Villa")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.astonvilla));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Burnley")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.burnley));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Chelsea")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.chelsea));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Crystal Palace")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.crystalpalace));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Everton")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.everton));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Hull City")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.hullcity));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Leicester City")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.leicestercity));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Liverpool")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.liverpool));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Man City")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.mancity));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Man United")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.manunited));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Newcastle")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.newcastle));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("QPR")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.qpr));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Southampton")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.southampton));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Stoke City")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.stokecity));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Sunderland")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.sunderland));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Swansea City")) {
            myDataset5[i]=(R.drawable.swanseacity);
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Tottenham")) {
            myDataset5[i]=(R.drawable.tottenham);
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("West Brom")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.westbrom));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("West Ham")) {
            myDataset5[i] = ((R.drawable.westham));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Almería")) {
            myDataset5[i]=(R.drawable.almeria);
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Athletic Bilbao")) {
            myDataset5[i]=(R.drawable.athleticbilbao);
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Athlético Madrid")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.athleticomadrid));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Barcalona")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.barcalona));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Celta Vigo")) {
            myDataset5[i]=(R.drawable.celtavigo);
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Córdoba")) {
            myDataset5[i]=(R.drawable.cordoba);
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Deportivo La Coruña")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.deportivolacoruna));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Eibar")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.eibar));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Elche")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.elche));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Espanyol")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.espanyol));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Getafe")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.getafe));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Granada")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.granada));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Levante")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.levante));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Málaga")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.malaga));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals( "Rayo Vallecano")) {
            myDataset5[i]=(R.drawable.rayovallecano);
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Real Madrid")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.realmadrid));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Real Sociedad")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.realsociedad));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Sevilla")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.sevilla));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Valencia")) {
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.valencia));
        } else if (myDataset2[i].equals("Villarreal")){
            myDataset5[i]=((R.drawable.villarreal));
        } else {
            myDataset5[i]=(R.drawable.imageismissing);
        }
}

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset, myDataset2, myDataset3, myDataset4, myDataset5);


}
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just a comment on your code style -  you use almost no access modifiers and have non-final fields in all-caps. It's not incorrect but it's a habit I would lean towards getting out of.

Comment: @Solarnum Thank you for the tips, I am new to Android development so any tip is welcome.

Comment: OH. Edit your post and remove your google analytics key and Parse public and private keys ASAP! Your device IMEI's are also in there and should probably be removed.

Comment: Also, generate new keys.

Comment: @Solarnum Holy crap thank you I can't believe I forgot to do that...

Comment: Lol, no problem. It happens. For sure generate new keys, though.

Comment: Another suggestion that I would make is that you use a map lookup table rather than that hideous if-else block. Just add a method like initMap and do this to initialize all your String, Integer pairs http://stackoverflow.com/a/15114370/3508192 and then just myDataset4[i] = map.get(myDataset[i]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start your intent for the dialog you can use `startActivityForResult` and then Override `onActivityResult` in `History.class` to retrieve the data passed along from `MainActivity.class`. Follow along [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html). If you need me to be more specific post your MainActivity.class too, but this should be enough information to get you on your way.